# Number of texture units (GL_TEXTUREi) in OpenGL 4 implementation in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

I use OpenGL 4 for some texture manipulations in visual C++.
The platform that I am working on is Visual Studio 2015. Having looked at the implementation of GL_TEXTUREi texture units, I found out that the total number is limited to 0 to 31 (32 in total).

Does it mean that the maximum number of textures that could be accessed at the same time is limited by 32?

This is from the implementation source code:

```
#define GL_TEXTURE0 0x84C0
#define GL_TEXTURE1 0x84C1
#define GL_TEXTURE2 0x84C2
#define GL_TEXTURE3 0x84C3
#define GL_TEXTURE4 0x84C4
#define GL_TEXTURE5 0x84C5
#define GL_TEXTURE6 0x84C6
...
#define GL_TEXTURE31 0x84DF
```

Comment: Related/Duplicate: [How many textures can usually I bind at once?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/30043/how-many-textures-can-usually-i-bind-at-once) (I cant actually vote as dupe because its from GameDev.SE)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The number of textures that can be bound to OpenGL is *not 32* or *16*. It is not what you get with `glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS, &texture_units);`. That function retrieves the number of textures that can be accessed *by the fragment shader*.

See, each [shader has *its own limit* of the number of textures it can use](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader#Resource_limitations). However, there is also a total number of textures that can be used, period. This is defined (in OpenGL) by `GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS`.

So there are two limits: the textures-per-stage, and the textures-total-bound.

OpenGL 3.x defines the minimum number for the per-stage limit to be 16, so hardware cannot have fewer than 16 textures-per-stage. It can have a higher limit, but you know you get at least 16. 3.x defines the minimum number for the textures-total-bound as 48. AKA: 16 * 3 stages. Similarly, GL 4.x defines the numbers to be 16 textures-per-stage, and 80 textures-total-bound (ie: 16 * 5 stages).

Again, these are the *minimum* numbers. Hardware can (and does) vary.

To use more texture units than there are defined enumerators, you take the value of `GL_TEXTURE0` and add it to the texture unit you want to manipulate:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + unit_index);
```